# connecting to Facebook in power BI designer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, powerbi

I've followed the Power BI Designer tutorial to connect to my own Facebook data through Power BI designer:

For some reason, no data loads at all. Below is an example of selecting the "Posts" type of connection to preview and load:

[image: Facebook connect image]

[image: No data in Preview image]

There doesn't appear to be a lot of support for this kind of problem, or it's not a problem and I'm doing something blatantly wrong that's not obvious to me. I've had the same problem connecting to Facebook with Microsoft Excel 2016.

Note: I am not trying to query my own Facebook data via my username; I understand they don't support that anymore.

Comment: As per example are you able to see data of 'microsoftbi'

Comment: yes, sorry; should've mentioned the tutorial microsoftbi data imported fine, but I wasn't able to duplicate it with my own data. it pulls partially sometimes, but usually nothing at all for any connection type.

Comment: It will be hard to help without knowing the exact API calls that are being made. Have you logged in with Facebook on the App?

Comment: @John ?????????????

Answer (score 0):

If you follow PowerBi Tutorial then you will notice that they are referring to there official page having username "Microsoftbi"

https://www.facebook.com/microsoftbi/

For Example, I have a facebook page having username 'MoviePsycho4U'.

See screenshots:

http://prntscr.com/hp340r

[Connecting to my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2af51.png)

Data is loaded properly
[Data Loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZYDe.png)

http://prntscr.com/hp34tj

Cheers